# Flatten a deeply nested object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I have an object with a triple nested objects. I want to flatten the object to clearly review the values and place in an HTML.

```
{
    "templateName": "Test template",
    "assignmentGroup": "Test template",
    "fields": [{
        "type": "Multi Select dropdown",
        "entry": [{
            "checked": false,
            "value": "govtBusinses",
            "displayValue": "Government Business Division"
        }, {
            "checked": true,
            "value": "privateSector",
            "displayValue": "Private Sector"
        }, {
            "checked": true,
            "value": "publicSector",   
            "displayValue": "Public Sector"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "Text Field",
        "entry": null
    }]
}
```

I tried flatting it, but I want it to be in desired format.

```
flattenObject = function(ob) {
        let toReturn = {};
        for (let i in ob) {
            if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((typeof ob[i]) === "object") {
                let flatObject = this.flattenObject(ob[i]);
                for (let x in flatObject) {
                    if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    toReturn[i + "." + x] = flatObject[x];
                }
            } else {
                toReturn[i] = ob[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(toReturn);
        return toReturn;
    };
```

Expected:

```
TemplateName  : "Test template"
Assignment Group : "sample"
Field 0 :
Type : Multiselect dropdown
Entry 0 :
checked : false
value : 
buisness: 
Entry 1:
checked : false
value : 
buisness: 
Field 1:
Type: 
.......
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: A quick google resulting in this. Maybe take a look at this code / similar google results... http://jsfiddle.net/S2hsS/ This is something pretty standard thus, there will be tons of results like this here on SO / elsewhere on the web :) That main trick would be to use recursion like you have in your example, so you're on the right path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have different values with same Key in object. I guess better way to achieve this would be to return array of objects instead.

try this:

```js
let obj = {
  "templateName": "Test template",
  "assignmentGroup": "Test template",
  "fields": [{
    "type": "Multi Select dropdown",
    "entry": [{
      "checked": false,
      "value": "govtBusinses",
      "displayValue": "Government Business Division"
    }, {
      "checked": true,
      "value": "privateSector",
      "displayValue": "Private Sector"
    }, {
      "checked": true,
      "value": "publicSector",
      "displayValue": "Public Sector"
    }]
  }, {
    "type": "Text Field",
    "entry": null
  }]
}

let fieldsCount = []

flattenObject = function(ob, toReturnArr) {
  for (let i in ob) {
    if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      continue;
    }
    if ((typeof ob[i]) === "object") {
      if (isNaN(i)) {
        fieldsCount[i] = fieldsCount[i] === undefined ? 0 : fieldsCount[i] + 1
        ob[i] && ob[i].length ? console.log(`${i}: ${fieldsCount[i]}`) : null;
      }
      toReturnArr = this.flattenObject(ob[i], toReturnArr);
    } else {
      console.log(`${i}: ${ob[i]}`);
      toReturnArr.push({
        [i]: ob[i]
      })
    }
  }
  return toReturnArr;
};

flattenObject(obj, [])
```

Result:

```
templateName: Test template
assignmentGroup: Test template
fields: 0
type: Multi Select dropdown
entry: 0
checked: false
value: govtBusinses
displayValue: Government Business Division
checked: true
value: privateSector
displayValue: Private Sector
checked: true
value: publicSector
displayValue: Public Sector
type: Text Field
```

PS: `{[key]: object[key]}` using variable for key value like [key] is the **ES6** feature.

Comment: Thanks but field and entry are not getting properly formatted as expected

Comment: I didn't focus on that, perhaps you can add another array to maintain fields count, like i have added in above snippet. Hope this helps.